# How to maximize use of partitioned volumes on my dedicated server?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

About a month or so ago, I rented a dedicated machine from server hosting company OVH. I am currently using the SP2 plan, which you can [read details on here](http://www.ovh.com/us/dedicated-servers/sp2.xml). My server has two mirrored 120GB SSDs, and is running **CentOS 6.4**.

[image: Quick overview of server stats]

The total amount of space that my server has is ample for my operations; however, it is partitioned rather oddly (or perhaps normally – I'm not a guru with this type of stuff yet).

I am Minecraft servers on machine, for example. I currently have all of my technical data for my Minecraft servers saved to `/var/opt/minecraft` for all of my files. One file, for example, reaches up to 67GB, and it is increasing. The currently volume that it is in has 90GB allotted there, which is only a fraction of the my total hard drive space on my machine.

My question is, **how can I better maximize the way I am using my hard drive space on my dedicated server so I don't have to worry about running out of room when the time comes?** Is there an "easy" way to do this, or will it result in a total reworking in the file structure?

Here is an overview of the disk, if this helps any.
[image: Overview of disk sizes]

I know there are some commands I may have to run to better calculate the way the disk space is used, so if you need more information, please just ask and explain what I have to do to provide that information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The currently volume that it is in has 90GB allotted there, which is
>   only a fraction of the my total hard drive space on my machine.

It is 75% of your 120GB which is a rather large fraction (3/4).

Two 120GB drives configured as a mirrored pair provides 120GB of space.

Comment: Wait, you have me more confused now – so, I'm basically limited to 120GB total either way you look at it?

Comment: Yes. RAID1 or mirrored drives duplicates the same data on both drives which means either can fail and you won't lose any data. The drawback is you get storage space equivalent to only one drive.